# Is it practical to add functionality to an ASP.net web application using Node and Express?

Tags: c#, asp.net, node.js

I've written some code in NodeJS for a relatively small web application.

I am now told that my client has decided that this functionality should be incorporated into a larger, existing ASP.net web application.

I'm wondering if it is practical and sensible to incorporate my NodeJS code into the existing web application, or if it makes more sense to rewrite the backend code in ASP.net.

The app that I've written is mostly independent from the umbrella app that it is to be incorporated into.  I think that if I could only get my Express server to gain access to some of the ASP.net session variables to identify the user, that would be sufficient to make it work.

I'm sure it's possible to do this, but I don't know if it's practical or sensible. 
 If it is practical, how would I be able to do it?

Comment: You could make your node.js code a microservice that runs in its own process and that the ASP.net app communicates with via http.  The only downsides are that node.js would have to be installed and there would be one additional process to start and monitor.  Other than that, microservices are a currently a trend to encapsulate functionality in it's own focused process rather than making giant monolothic apps.  And, one of the benefits, is you can mix/match technologies easily.

Comment: @jfriend00, can you suggest any resources where I might learn something about this pattern?

Comment: Just search for "microservices architecture".  Lots and lots of articles.

Comment: As to whether this is practical or sensible, it really depends.  It adds some extra complication to deploying and monitoring the app, but provides better encapsulation and isolation of functionality into smaller, manageable, testable blocks, avoiding large, monolothic apps.  It's a trend now because some believe the tradeoff to splitting things out into microservices is favorable overall.